# sorting a List<Object> numerically and alphabetically using Object product field

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object, collections

```java
List<ShipInventoryReportDataVO> lstShipInvData = shipInventoryReportDAO
    .getShippableInventoryReportData(inputVO, true);
```

`ShipInventoryReportDataVO` is my object class and getting the data from a stored procedure. In `ShipInventoryReportDataVO` object class I have a field called `productCode` and the data of productCode will in alphanumeric like

```
0123, 
654, 
sparem, 
3205, 
the wholeland, 
10, 
1.
```

when I am sorting the `productCode` which is in object class, I am getting the output as

```
0123
1
10
3205
654
sparem
wholeland.
```

this is the code I tried to sort

```java
List<ShipInventoryReportDataVO> lstShipInvData = shipInventoryReportDAO.getShippableInventoryReportData(inputVO, true);
                
Collections.sort(lstShipInvData, 
    (o1, o2) -> 
        (o1.getProductCode().compareTo(o2.getProductCode()))
);
```

and this

```java
lstShipInvData = (List) lstShipInvData.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
            ShipInventoryReportDataVO::getProductCode
        ))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

both the codes gets output as above

but I need the output as below

```
1
10
654
0123
3205
sparem
wholeland
```

This is the code which i tried now

```
List<ShipInventoryReportDataVO> productCodes = shipInventoryReportDAO.getShippableInventoryReportData(inputVO, true);

Comparator<String> byProductCode = Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)
                        .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());

productCodes.sort(Comparator.comparing(
                        ShipInventoryReportDataVO::getProductCode, byProductCode
));

productCodes.forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.println(productCodes.toString());
```

Comment: Make ShipInventoryReportDataVO Comparable and write your custom logic on the interface implementation.

Comment: could not get the needed output

Comment: @VijayRathod, please edit and update your _question_ with the details what has not worked.

Comment: @AlexRudenko Probably didn't do anything, just waiting for you to do it...

Comment: @m0skit0, nice attempt to bite... :)

Comment: I tried the below-answered code but did not worked out. The data is as it is not al alla sorted sorry for the late message i'm not getting messages

Comment: i posted the changes i have made

Answer (score 0):

The expected output shows that the data should be sorted first by the length of the product codes and then in alphabetic order.

This can be implemented with the help of chaining comparators and using [`Comparator.comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor, <? super U> keyComparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-):

```java
List<ShipInventoryReportDataVO> productCodes = Arrays.asList(
        new ShipInventoryReportDataVO("0123"),
        new ShipInventoryReportDataVO("654"),
        new ShipInventoryReportDataVO("sparem"),
        new ShipInventoryReportDataVO("3205"),
        new ShipInventoryReportDataVO("the wholeland"),
        new ShipInventoryReportDataVO("10"),
        new ShipInventoryReportDataVO("1")
);

Comparator<String> byProductCode = Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)
    .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());

productCodes.sort(Comparator.comparing(
    ShipInventoryReportDataVO::getProductCode, byProductCode
));

productCodes.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output

```
1
10
654
0123
3205
sparem
the wholeland
```